# Is finding the explicit formula for a linear homogeneous recurrence relation the same as solving for such relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Is finding the explicit formula for a linear homogeneous recurrence relation the same process as solving for this relation? For example, if I solved

$ b_n = b_{n−1} + 12 b_{n−2}$ with initial values $ b_0 = −2 $ and $ b_1 = 20$,

would the solution $ b_n = 2 \cdot 4^n - 4(-3)^n $ be the explicit formula?

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g(n)+%3D+g(n-1)+%2B+12g(n-2),+g(0)+%3D+-2,+g(1)+%3D+20), the solution is $2^{2n+1}-4(-3)^n$. However, since $2^{2n+1} = 2*4^n$, your solution is correct.

Comment: Is my solution the same as the explicit formula for this recurrence relation?

Comment: @smith1453 Welcome to MSE! Here you are able to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which is an excellent language for writting mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$. Multiplying both sides of the recurrence by $z^n$ and summing over $n\geqslant 2$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty b_nz^n = \sum_{n=2}^\infty b_{n-1}z^n + 12\sum_{n=2}^\infty b_{n-2}z^n.\tag1
$$
Writing $(1)$ in terms of $B(z)$, we have
$$
B(z) - b_0 - b_1z = z(B(z) - b_0) + 12z^2B(z).\tag2
$$
Substituting $b_0=-$2 and $b_1=20$ into $(2)$ and solving for $B(z)$, we have 
$$
B(z) = \frac{-2+11z}{1-z-12z^2}\tag3
$$
Using partial fraction decomposition, we may write the RHS of $(3)$ as
$$
-4\left(\frac1{1+3z}\right)+2\left(\frac1{1-4z}\right),\tag4
$$
and expanding $(4)$ as a power series yields
$$
B(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(4(-1)^{n+1}3^n + 2\cdot 4^n \right)z^n.
$$
It follows that $$b_n = 4(-1)^{n+1}3^n + 2\cdot 4^n,\ n\geqslant2.$$